# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException thrown on Pusher Initialization

Tags: c#, .net, pusher

On occasion, I'm getting a Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException when initializing. I'm using the PusherClient library as-is from Git. The exception is thrown on a different thread, which is particularly troublesome. I'm not doing anything special in the init. I think I got this code directly from the Pusher .NET examples:

```
if (!_isInitialized)
{
    _pusher = new Pusher(_pusherKey);
    _pusher.Connected += PusherConnected;
    _pusher.ChannelAuthEndpoint = _authUri + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(_clientName);
    _pusher.ConnectionStateChanged += PusherOnConnectionStateChanged;
    _pusher.Connect();
}
```

The Pusher Auth Endpoint, which is the only other component I have in this initialization chain, uses the PusherProvider (provided in PusherRESTDotNet library) to authenticate the private and presence channel requests. There are no exceptions being thrown in the auth provider.

I can add additional logging to these libraries to discover what is being sent, and what's causing the JSON library to hiccup, but I'm not sure what the recovery path should be from a Pusher perspective; I'm trying to stay a black-box consumer of the Pusher .NET libraries. Any ideas/thoughts are appreciated.

I'm getting the following out of the Pusher trace log when it succeeds:

```
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket opened OK.
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket message received: {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"24213.760310\"}"}
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket message received: {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":"{}","channel":"private-HW-PusherChannel"}
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket message received: {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":"{\"presence\":{\"count\":2,\"ids\":[\"24213.760310\",\"24305.693765\"],\"hash\":{\"24213.760310\":{\"name\":\"SITE2\"},\"24305.693765\":{\"name\":\"SITE1\"}}}}","channel":"presence-channel"}
```

And the following when it fails:

```
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket opened OK.
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket message received: {"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\"socket_id\":\"24102.767432\"}"}
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket message received: {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":"{\"presence\":{\"count\":2,\"ids\":[\"24102.767432\",\"24305.693765\"],\"hash\":{\"24102.767432\":{\"name\":\"SITE2\"},\"24305.693765\":{\"name\":\"SITE1\"}}}}","channel":"presence-channel"}
Pusher Information: 0 : Websocket message received: {"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":null,"message":"Cannot broadcast client event (connection not subscribed to channel private-HW-PusherChannel)"}}
```

The full stack is below:

```
Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'data', line 1, position 32.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsStringInternal()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ResolvePropertyAndConstructorValues(JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectFromNonDefaultConstructor(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ConstructorInfo constructorInfo, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultConstructor)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType[T](String value, T anonymousTypeObject)
   at PusherClient.Connection.websocket_MessageReceived(Object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e) in C:\svn\non-scm\pusher-dotnet-client\PusherClient\Connection.cs:line 98
   at WebSocket4Net.WebSocket.FireMessageReceived(String message)
   at WebSocket4Net.Command.Text.ExecuteCommand(WebSocket session, WebSocketCommandInfo commandInfo)
   at WebSocket4Net.WebSocket.ExecuteCommand(WebSocketCommandInfo commandInfo)
   at WebSocket4Net.WebSocket.OnDataReceived(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at WebSocket4Net.WebSocket.client_DataReceived(Object sender, DataEventArgs e)
   at SuperSocket.ClientEngine.ClientSession.OnDataReceived(Byte[] data, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   at SuperSocket.ClientEngine.AsyncTcpSession.ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at SuperSocket.ClientEngine.AsyncTcpSession.SocketEventArgsCompleted(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.ExecutionCallback(Object ignored)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationSuccess(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
```

Comment: As the exeption suggests, JSON deserializer encountered some unexpected data. Way more information is needed to troubleshoot your problem, like what clients expects to receive, what server sends. What classes are used for serialization and deserialization.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand there's unexpected data, however I'm not sending anything. This is all on initialization. I edited the OP to include additional info on how/what I'm using. As I edited above, I can add more logging to find out what's being sent to the JSON library, but I'm not sure how to recover.

Comment: Is the .Connect throwing a 500 Error? That could make it die unexpectedly.

Comment: No, the .Connect connects fine. In the ConnectionStateChanged handler it even goes from "Connecting", to "Connected". It seems to crash right after dumping channel presence.

Comment: Just to confirm, it looks like you are using this library https://github.com/leggetter/pusher-dotnet-client. Correct? What would help is to show the raw String message that is being parsed and causing the exception. It should be available via https://github.com/leggetter/pusher-dotnet-client/blob/master/PusherClient/Connection.cs#L95

Comment: I just edited to include the Pusher trace logs. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: So I looked into this a bit and it turns out that in the cases where this fails, the pusher:error data payload actually contains a JSON object vs. a string. I know this is obvious, but I'm now left wondering how to fix? I Think this message is being sent from the Pusher server. I could put a "fix" in that would escape the JSON object back into a string, but I'm not sure this fixes anything. The real problem seems to be that my client isn't really subscribed to the private pusher channel when the "Subscribed" event is fired. Thoughts?